# .htaccess -> rewrite-strtolower doesn't work when I upload to web host

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Okay, I am once again posting a question that I had to answer for myself because I could not find it anywhere.

I was writing a .htaccess file to force all characters to lowercase. I found this solution, which seemed good:

https://www.simonholywell.com/post/2012/11/force-lowercase-urls-rewrite-php/

Except that the filename and variable names were hideously unwieldy. I had to fix that. So I tried to make my own version of the files, and renamed the filename from "rewrite-strtolower" to "lowercase" and the variable name from "rewrite-strtolower-url" to "address". I tested them on my home server, and the result was beautiful: everything worked!

UNFORTUNATELY, when I tried to upload them to my host, they did not work.

What? The code looked perfect. It worked on my home server... Why not theirs? After going through my code line by line and deciding that it should be perfect, I contacted my host and asked if there was some setting that they had to adjust on their end.

They said no, of course, and one technician was kind enough to run the tutorial that I ran, but when he ran it, his version worked! How!? I compared his version to mine for a long time, and concluded that the only difference was the variable names and file names that we had used - he copied the precise filename and variable name from the tutorial.

The following is the (relevant) content of my .htaccess and lowercase.php files... can you spot my mistake?

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(img|css) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} [A-Z]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule (.*) lowercase.php?address=$1 [QSA,L]
```

lowercase.php:

```
<!--
Copyright (C) 2017 Peace Seeker

This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.

This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  

See the GNU General Public License for more details.  
<http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>

DISCLAIMER: USER CONTENT IS LICENSED BY INDIVIDUAL CONTRIBUTORS. ONLY THE CODE STRUCTURES OF THIS FILE AND ALL MATERIALS PUBLISHED BY LUCAS MCDONALD aka AISO IPPUDU MILELE aka TRANSIENT ANIMA ARE COPYRIGHTED (i.e., COPYLEFTED) BY THIS AGREEMENT. ALL OTHER CONTENT IS OWNED BY THE CONTRIBUTORS WHO CONTRIBUTED IT.
-->

<?php
if(isset($_GET['address'])) {
    $url = $_GET['address'];
    unset($_GET['address']);
    $params = http_build_query($_GET);
    if(strlen($params)) {
        $params = '?' . $params;
    }
    header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/' . strtolower($url) . $params, true, 301);
    exit;
}
header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
die('Unable to convert the URL to lowercase. You must supply a URL to work upon.');
?>
```

This code worked on my home server, but it did not work on the web server... what could be the problem? Was there a syntax that had become deprecated? Scroll down to my answer if you can't find the problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually the COMMENTS. For some reason that remains unknown to me, HTML5 comments BEFORE the PHP code will break the efforts of .htaccess to run my lowercase.php file on my web host's server, but not on my home server... However, if I simply moved the comments below the PHP code, all was well!

If anyone can improve this answer by telling me WHY HTML5 comments are allowed to precede PHP code in, say, a .php file that has a bunch of HTML5 code, but *sometimes* not allowed inside of a .php file that has only PHP code (or perhaps not allowed inside of a .php file that will be called by .htaccess), I would be happy to learn some details about this issue!

(As mentioned in comment by Croises, apparently the comments simply cannot precede PHP headers. I still don't totally understand why...)

Comment: You can't send html code (like comments) before headers.

Comment: Do you have any idea why this worked on my home server? Because I had comments above all PHP code in my home-server version of the file, and it was totally responsive...

Comment: You can send html code before php, but you can't before header. http://php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php